# Install TFS 2008 on Windows 2008 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm trying to install Team Foundation Server using 2 machines:

**Machine1**:
OS: Windows 2008 Server
Installed applications:
    SQL Server 2008
    SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services

**Machine2**:
OS: Windows 2008 Server
Installed applications:
    SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services
    Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
    WSS/Reporting Services connector

The plan is to install TFS 2008 on machine 2 but after a lot of struggle I'm getting an error 28805 while installing TFS. I've tried to apply every solution I was able to find on the web without success. Almost all solutions I've found so far target Windows 2003 and SQL Server 2005.

Has anyone been able to deploy TFS 2008 on a configuration as the one I've described?

Thanks,

Pedro

Comment: I think this question belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the [installation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123135155/http://geekswithblogs.net/etiennetremblay/archive/2008/02/05/windows-2008--tfs-2008-it-works-but.aspx) article created by Etienne